# In a Loopback.js application, how to deal with data migrations when new code or data fields are deployed?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, data-migration

What is the recommended way to deal with data migrations. Here is an example:

We add a feature to the app which requires us to add a field, `time_zone` to the `Account` model. When we deploy this code, the `time_zone` field will be empty for all of the existing users.

Perhaps another wrinkle is that the `time_zone` needs to be fetched via an HTTP call.

How should be dealing with this type of scenario?